# Dynamic Content in a Block

Tags: 7, blocks, hooks

I'm new to drupal. I'm trying to do something very simple, but feel I'm going the wrong way about it.

I have html content that is in a block on my homepage. There is a button in this block that is a link to a content page.

I simply want to change this button to a different button, if the user is logged in.

I've read that using php filtering is the wrong way to go about this. What would be the best practice for doing this?

Comment: Would button have different actions for loggedin & non loggedin user?? If not @shabir ans is correct. If yes you can enable php filter and you will get php input format to apply conditions. Though php filter in non recommended for security measures.

Comment: Yea, two different actions. @jphelan's solution seems like it will work best.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by simple css rule, no php, no logic

Inspect your element and check the body classes you will see class "logged-in" for logged in users and class "not-logged-in" for anonymous users. Just apply your changes like so:

```
.logged-in <block-class> <button> { // your style }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create two blocks and set the Roles Visibility settings to *anonymous user* or *authenticated user* depending on which one you want to display to that group. That way you don't have to enable php filter.